# Maven not able to build Angularjs project

Tags: angularjs, maven

When I am executing mvn -Pdev clean install all my projects getting installed except V-WEB.V-web has angularjs dependency.Can you let me know how to resolve the below issue

```
] V app ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.344 s]
[INFO] V parent pom .................................... SUCCESS [  2.472 s]
[INFO] V-common ........................................ SUCCESS [ 11.996 s]
[INFO] V input modules ................................. SUCCESS [ 18.442 s]
[INFO] V consolidation engine .......................... SUCCESS [ 14.378 s]
[INFO] V extraction engine ............................. SUCCESS [  7.134 s]
[INFO] V-database ...................................... SUCCESS [  1.738 s]
[INFO] V-web ........................................... FAILURE [ 44.135 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:43 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-30T19:34:54+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 53M/443M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here is the error

```
---
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (npm-install) on project V-web: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Use -X with your maven command and check the detailed output and post it here.

Comment: thanks but the issue got resolved .I needed to use phantomjs 1.9 version